# Image upload from iOS Swift to Node.js and Express backend

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, image-uploading

Here I'm trying to upload an image using POST request. Application backend is MEAN. When I'm trying with Postman, it is uploading successfully.

But ios datatask showing undefined file.

Here is my MEAN code.

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'images/profile_images')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {

            var getFileExt = function(fileName){
                var fileExt = fileName.split(".");
                if( fileExt.length === 1 || ( fileExt[0] === "" && fileExt.length === 2 ) ) {
                    return "";
                }
                return fileExt.pop();
            }
            cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + getFileExt(file.originalname))
        }
    });

var upload = multer({ storage: storage})
var type = upload.single('profile_pic');

    app.post('/images' ,type ,function(req,res) {
        console.log(req.body, req.file , req);
});
```

> output
>
> file:     { fieldname: 'profile_pic',
>        originalname: '1.png',
>        encoding: '7bit',
>        mimetype: 'image/png',
>        destination: 'images/profile_images',
>        filename: '1486012211611.png',
>        path: 'images/profile_images/1486012211611.png',
>        size: 144 },   __onFinished: null }

Here is my Swift code:

```
@IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {
    let api = URL.init(string: "http://localhost:3000/images")
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: api!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()



    request.setValue("multipart/form-data, boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let imge:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage.init(named: "image1")!, 1)!;


    let body = NSMutableData()

    let fname = "profile_pic.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(imge)

    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let session: URLSession = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        print(data, response, error!)
    }

    task.resume()

}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```

> Output at terminal,
>
> undefined

and the image is not uploading.

Can you help me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Found the answer already?

Answer (score 0):

You are working on localhost. Alamofire cannot send image to localhost server.

[Alamofire with localhost connection problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337206/alamofire-with-localhost-connection-problems)

Comment: Could you add a reference to support that claim